# "Intro to Statistical Learning" Chapter 5 - Resampling p.191

Tags: r, mean, predict

Can someone help with the usage of this line of code:

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train=sample(392,196)
lm.fit=lm(mpg~horsepower,data=Auto,subset=train)
attach(Auto)
mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,Auto))[-train]^2)
```

I'm looking for help on last line of code.  Can someone explain what it is doing? 
(specifically the syntax "mpg-predict.." and usage of the "-")

For reference this comes from:
"An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R".  Chapter 5 - Re-sampling. (p.191)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I think you are referring to this page.

There are two `-` here.

The first one in `mpg-predict` is just the ordinary minus sign. `predict` is the function for model prediction. Read `?predict` and `?predict.lm` for more. The reason that you can take subtraction between `mpg` and prediction result, is that you have `attach` the dataset. Alternatively, use `Auto$mpg - predict(lm.fit, Auto)`.

The second one with `-train` is for subsetting. Here is a simple example:

```
x <- 1:5
x[-(2:3)]  ## drop element 2 to 3
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!! I meant to indicate that I meant the first "-" . And that makes sense now.  I didn't realize it was simply a subtraction...I was thinking the first "-" was being used like the "subset" command.  Thank you